# Plot point on existing (or newly created) image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on PDF generation logic, and would like to be able to plot points on images within the PDF at exact locations.

To ensure those points are plotted exactly where I want them, I'd like to generate an image that I could insert into the PDF, which would have an object (point, circle, etc) at an exact and known location.

What's the fastest/easiest way to take an image and add something to it at (x, y). Online tool? Easy ruby/rails solution? Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use the Prawn gem: 
https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails

Here is an example from the manual (http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf) of drawing ac circle in a border as specific (x,y).
Please note that (0,0) is the bottom left corner.

```
stroke_axis
stroke_circle [0, 0], 10
bounding_box([100, 300], :width => 300, :height => 200) do
 stroke_bounds
 stroke_circle [0, 0], 10
end
```

In your case, after you locate the image in a certain location, you can calculate where exactly you want to draw the point (according to image height and width)

Comment: The whole point of what I'm trying to accomplish is to make sure something like Prawn puts it in the right spot on the image. I want to have a pre-defined marker on the image I import into Prawn.